# Word-request for equivalent of "Anniversary" but for time period of a month

Tags: single-word-requests

As defined by OED, Anniversary is,

> the date on which an event took place or an institution was founded in a previous year.

Is their any word in the same context which can be used for addressing the events after one month. For instance, I have to congratulate a friend on his marriage after one month.

P.S. I know that we can always keep it simple and convey the most, but I am just curious to know if there is any word equivalent to 'anniversary' but for the time period of one month.

Comment: As it happens. the honeymoon derives from a custom of drinking mead (honey ale) for one month.  But that's geeky and embarrassing. Sorry!

Answer (score 2):

I have not found a word for this in the standard dictionaries. However, a common usage is--

> **Mensiversary**

MEN-SI-VER-SA-RY (mèn´se-vûr´se-rê) noun 
1. The monthly recurring date of a past event, especially one of 
historical, national, or personal importance: a first date 
mensiversary; the mensiversary of the founding of Nerstone Pictures. 
2. A celebration commemorating such a date. 
from Latin: mensis, month + versus, past participle of vertere, to turn.

If the word for the commemoration of a yearly event is anniversary, by 
analogy the logical word for the commemoration of a monthly event 
should be "mensiversary." "Anniversary" comes from the Latin "annum," 
meaning year. (The "versary" part comes from a Latin word referring 
to turning.) The Latin word for month is "mensis."

([Source](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=mensiversary))

Comment: That's the common usage? Funny how I've heard "monthly anniversary" umpteen million times, and this is the first I've seen of this Mensiversary word.

Comment: Similar question [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/593433/alternate-formulations-for-four-month-anniversary-one-third-of-a-year) for four months, in case you have any idea.

Answer (score 1):

Especially when it comes to dating and relationships the term **one month anniversary**, **two month anniversary** is frequently used.

Eg.

> It's Ben's and my one month anniversary, so we're going out to a fancy restaurant for dinner.

Comment: Hmmm I'm not sure about the grammar of 'Ben and I's' anyone?

Comment: ask yourself if you would say *It's I's anniversary* and you have your answer.

Comment: @JimMack Have edited it to 'Ben and my' and it still doesn't seem to make sense.

Comment: "Remember Ben? It's our anniversary..." (-: Actually, the "Ben's and my" you now have seems fine to me.

Comment: Similar question [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/593433/alternate-formulations-for-four-month-anniversary-one-third-of-a-year) for four months, in case you have any idea.

Comment: Frequently and deplorably.

Answer (score 0):

I always say lunaversary, which is etymologically just as justifiable, but doesn't have the same connotations to me (and other women) as mensiversary.

Comment: add mooniversary.  You just have to.

Comment: I spell it *luniversary*.

Answer (score 0):

I did research and I found the word "**mensiversary**" and it refers to a celebration for every month. I'm positive it's what you're looking for as it's just like an "*anniversary*" but celebrated every month. also, I asked some people and found out some say "**lunaversary**" which is just like mensiversary. I did some research, and it's proved that this word is correct. therefore, you can also say "**month anniversary**" as it is thee most popular word for this term.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

I'd like to suggest minaversary as an option. Derived from the Greek word for month - minas and -versary from anniversary. The connotation is twofold, it is monthly as well as minor, of lesser importance or lower in 'class' than anniversary.