# Alternate formulations for "four-month anniversary" (one-third of a year)

Tags: time, prefixes, fractions

Looking for alternate formulations to *four-month anniversary*, a formulation that would **highlight the fact that one third of a year** has gone by since a certain date.

For six months there is the word *semianniversary*, but I can't think of a word or formulation to express the same notion for a four-month period. I read *quadrimensiversary* somewhere but that's not a real word.

Note: this question is related in theme to:

[Word-request for equivalent of "Anniversary" but for time period of a month](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/255310/word-request-for-equivalent-of-anniversary-but-for-time-period-of-a-month)

Comment: ***Quadrimester*** is a rare term that refers to a four month period. https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/quadrimester

Answer (score 1):

The expression [four-month anniversary](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=four-month%20anniversary%2C%20four%20month%20anniversary&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&case_insensitive=on&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cfour%20-%20month%20anniversary%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cfour%20month%20anniversary%3B%2Cc0)  appears to be more commonly used in recent decades.

From [Four Funerals and a Wedding: Resilience in a Time of Grief](https://books.google.it/books?id=1MSfDQAAQBAJ&pg=PT170&dq=%22four%20month%20anniversary%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&source=gb_mobile_search&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiZrYHEosH5AhXgQ_EDHXnECw0Q6AF6BAgGEAM#v=onepage&q=%22four%20month%20anniversary%22&f=fals):

> Am I okay because I know I did my very best for Wease? I hope so. As the four-month anniversary of Joe's death neared, I thought.

From [How to Get a Guy to Propose to You In 365 Days](https://books.google.it/books?id=xSaWDwAAQBAJ&pg=PT51&dq=%22four%20month%20anniversary%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&source=gb_mobile_search&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjin5DlocH5AhWgXfEDHYWcDmcQ6AF6BAgDEAM#v=onepage&q=%22four%20month%20anniversary%22&f=false):

> Should you decide to get a gift to commemorate your four month anniversary with Mr. Right, check out the various creative ideas by way of the Google search engine.